# SQL Query Optimization: Running totals

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, cumulative-sum

I need some help in optimizing a SQL query I am using to assign a running cost if none is supplied.

```
SELECT *
,Running_Cost = CASE WHEN Cost = 0 OR Cost IS NULL
                THEN (SELECT TOP 1 Cost 
                            FROM #Results
                            WHERE (InvoiceYear < t.InvoiceYear
                                   OR (InvoiceYear = t.InvoiceYear
                                   AND InvoiceMonth <= t.InvoiceMonth))
                                   AND (Cost <> 0 OR Cost IS NULL)
                            ORDER BY Invoicemonth, Invoiceyear DESC)
                ELSE Cost
                END
FROM #Results t
```

I have tried coming up with a different method to Achieve this but failed as this method does not allow any filtering

```
, cost2 = CASE WHEN Cost = 0 OR Cost IS NULL
               THEN LAG(Cost,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceMonth,InvoiceYear) 
               ELSE Cost 
          END
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in the SQL standard --

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(COALESCE(COST,0)) OVER (ORDER BY INVOICEMONTH, INVOICEYEAR RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RUN_COST
FROM #Results t
```

more information ms-sql:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017